# PHP: Warning: json_decode() expects parameter 1 to be string, object given in

Tags: php, json

I am trying for get one field value from json response but I am unable to get it. My PHP code is like below

```
$servers    = $sp->server_list();
print_r ($servers);
```

Its giving me result like below

```
stdClass Object ( [data] => Array ( [0] => stdClass Object ( [id] => S9rr4Un0SYlPGR6E [name] => localhost [autoupdates] => 1 [firewall] => [deny_unknown_domains] => [lastconn] => 1544645254 [lastaddress] => 50.116.20.23 [datecreated] => 1511884238 [plan] => grandfathered_coach [available_runtimes] => Array ( [0] => php5.4 [1] => php5.5 [2] => php5.6 [3] => php7.0 [4] => php7.1 [5] => php7.2 [6] => php7.3 ) ) ) )
```

I want get value called id from it and want use it in my php. I have tried json decode method like below

```
$decoded_data = json_decode($servers,TRUE); 
$myid = $decoded_data['data']['id'];
```

its giving me error like below

```
Warning: json_decode() expects parameter 1 to be string, object given in C:\xampp\htdocs\code\new2.php on line 11
```

I have searched many questions and answer here but I am unable to get it resolved. Let me know if someone can help me. Thanks a lot.

Comment: There may be a JSON response at some point, but if so, something in the `server_list()` method has already decoded it for you.

Comment: @Don'tPanic I have got solved using answer but I am getting error called Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Cannot use object of type stdClass as array in  when I use it with $systemUser = $sp->sysuser_create($server_id, $system_user, $system_user_password); Let me know if you can help me for it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$servers is an object with key data which is an array. You can access the first element in the array using index 0 then you can get the id.

Json decode is not needed as $servers is already an object. You use json decode to go from json string to object. You can learn more about [PHP JSON decode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php)

```
$servers = $sp->server_list();
echo $myId = $servers->data[0]->id;
```

Comment: its giving me error like  Warning: json_decode() expects parameter 1 to be string, object given in C:\xampp\htdocs\code\new2.php on line 11

Comment: this error in $decoded_data = json_decode($servers,TRUE); 
this line

Comment: You dont need to use json decode. As servers in not a json string. It is an object.

Comment: @AbraCadaver what if its array casted. Do u know if the nested object will need to be array casted separately. Either way i have removed it as an alternative.

Comment: You would have to cast both `(array)$servers;` and `(array)$servers['data'][0]->id;`

Comment: @AbraCadaver answer is working fine but now in my another same method is not working, its giving error like Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Cannot use object of type stdClass as array in....my method is $systemUser = $sp->sysuser_create($server_id, $system_user, $system_user_password);

Comment: @MohammadC its working fine but when I use same for my method called $systemUser = $sp->sysuser_create($server_id, $system_user, $system_user_password);     its giving me error like Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Cannot use object of type stdClass as array in

Comment: Sorry. I have not understood what has led to this error. Maybe post another question. Providing all relevant code leading up to the error. With full error message.